# How can exceptions in graphene-django be conditionally logged?

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

Whenever exceptions are raised they're logged in the console (and in Sentry if it's used).

Many of these exceptions are only intended to be shown to the user. For example, [`django-graphql-jwt` raises the `PermissionDenied` exception](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/blob/master/graphql_jwt/exceptions.py#L14) for the [`login_required` decorator](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/blob/master/graphql_jwt/decorators.py#L48).

The problem is this pollutes the console output during testing/development and logs valid errors to Sentry during production. For exceptions such as the example above, that's only intended to be shown to the user, *not* logged.

As a workaround I've tried writing middleware that catches any exceptions thrown:

```py
class ExceptionFilterMiddleware:
    IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS = (
        # Local exceptions
        ValidationException,
        # Third-party exceptions
        JSONWebTokenExpired,
        PermissionDenied,
    )

    def on_error(self, error):
        if not isinstance(error, self.IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS):
            return error

    def resolve(self, next, *args, **kwargs):
        return next(*args, **kwargs).catch(self.on_error)
```

But if an exception is caught or not returned, it no longer populates the `errors` field in query/mutation output. Therefore all errors are logged, there's no way to conditionally log exceptions.

This means the only solution is to create a logging filter like the following:

```py
def skip_valid_exceptions(record):
    """
    Skip exceptions for errors only intended to be displayed to the API user.
    """
    skip: bool = False

    if record.exc_info:
        exc_type, exc_value = record.exc_info[:2]
        skip = isinstance(exc_value, valid_exceptions)

    return not skip
```

But this doesn't work either because `record.exc_info` is `None` whenever an error is thrown with Graphene, therefore it's not possible to conditionally filter out exceptions based on their type.

Is there a solution for this? This seems like it'd be a common issue but I've had trouble finding any solution.

Alternatively I could just not use exceptions for displaying errors to the API user, but this would mean putting errors into the query result's `data.errors` field instead of `errors`. This is a standard and requires the front-end logic to be adapted (such as Apollo's error handling), which isn't ideal. It also means no functionality can be used from third-party libraries (like django-graphql-jwt) that throw exceptions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm dealing with this now myself

Comment: @JensAstrup this was a pretty long time ago, but IIRC I don't think I found any solution. graphene-django has fairly poor handling for this. I opened an issue on GitHub but nothing has happened: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/780

Answer (score 3):

Try this. First ensure that intended exceptions are `GraphQLError` or descendants of it.

Then create a log filter like so:

```py
import logging
from graphql import GraphQLError

class GraphQLLogFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    Filter GraphQL errors that are intentional.

    Any exceptions of type GraphQLError that are raised on purpose 
    to generate errors for GraphQL responses will be silenced from logs. 
    Other exceptions will be displayed so they can be tracked down.
    """
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            etype, _, _ = record.exc_info
            if etype == GraphQLError:
                return None
        if record.stack_info and 'GraphQLError' in record.stack_info:
            return None
        if record.msg and 'GraphQLError' in record.msg:
            return None

        return True
```

Use in your settings:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    # Prevent graphql exception from displaying in console
    'filters': {
        'graphql_log_filter': {
            '()': GraphQLLogFilter,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'graphql.execution.utils': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'filters': ['graphql_log_filter'],
        },
    },
}
```

Related resources:

- [Discussion on Graphene library](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/513)
- [Django logging documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/)
- [How filters work](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects)

Comment: hello @matt-sanders, tried to use this approch, but did not managed to make it work. firstly, I have not found graphql.execution.utils module, only graphql.execution.execute - but it did not help.

Any ideas how to make it work with recent version of graphene/graphene-django?

Comment: @Q-bart Unfortunately I'm not using graphene-django anymore, this may be a change in more recent versions?

Comment: gotcha. Just what are you using now for graphql? maybe for django?